# Trim dynamic column value

Tags: sql, dynamic, ssms

Have a column with a value like this, that I want to compare against another table column:

```
FamilyName: 'SMITH'  FirstName: 'John'  MiddleName: ''  SingleName: ''  DateOfBirth: '01-Jan-1990'
```

Problem with this being that value has dynamic length due to different names in the database, how would I go about trimming it so that it would only display (in the above example) 'John'? (without quotes)

Want to do this for all values in the query, not just this one.

Comment: Not sure if regex is supported in ssms. If it is ,then you can try extracting the FirstName by using regex like this FirstName:'(.*?)'.* and then extracting the first group.

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world did you break rules of normalization and stuff multiple fields into a single column? This is one of the biggest anti-patterns in SQL land! At least store the data as a JSON in a JSON column datatype. Then it's simple to reference the fields within the JSON.

SQL Server lacks regular expression support. You could write a CLR stored procedure (examples are out there on the interwebs) that implement regexp for SQL Server (you can also join the rest of us and bang your head too on the Microsoft edifice to add support for regexp after decades of them ignoring the sensible approach).

For the sake of maximum pain, here is an approach using PATINDEX, that should probably be wrapped in an UDF:

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING(
    craziness, 
    PATINDEX('FamilyName: ''%', craziness) + DATALENGTH('FamilyName: '''), 
    PATINDEX('%'' FirstName: ''%', craziness) - PATINDEX('FamilyName: ''%', craziness) - DATALENGTH('FamilyName: ''')
  ) AS family_name_field,
  SUBSTRING(
    craziness, 
    PATINDEX('%'' FirstName: ''%', craziness) + DATALENGTH(''' FirstName: '''), 
    PATINDEX('%'' MiddleName: ''%', craziness) - PATINDEX('%'' FirstName: ''%', craziness) - DATALENGTH(''' FirstName: ''')
  ) AS first_name_field,
  SUBSTRING(
    craziness, 
    PATINDEX('%'' MiddleName: ''%', craziness) + DATALENGTH(''' MiddleName: '''), 
    PATINDEX('%'' SingleName: ''%', craziness) - PATINDEX('%'' MiddleName: ''%', craziness) - DATALENGTH(''' MiddleName: ''')
  ) AS middle_name_field,
  SUBSTRING(
    craziness, 
    PATINDEX('%'' SingleName: ''%', craziness) + DATALENGTH(''' SingleName: '''), 
    PATINDEX('%'' DateOfBirth: ''%', craziness) - PATINDEX('%'' SingleName: ''%', craziness) - DATALENGTH(''' SingleName: ''')
  ) AS single_name_field,
  SUBSTRING(
    craziness, 
    PATINDEX('%'' DateOfBirth: ''%', craziness) + DATALENGTH(''' DateOfBirth: '''), 
    DATALENGTH(craziness) - PATINDEX('%'' DateOfBirth: ''%', craziness) - DATALENGTH(''' DateOfBirth: ''')
  ) AS dob_field
FROM (
  VALUES ('FamilyName: ''Smith'' FirstName: ''John'' MiddleName: ''Patrick'' SingleName: ''Hogan'' DateOfBirth: ''01-Jan-1990''')
) s(craziness);
```

Other thoughts:
You have different casing on the fields (SMITH is upper, others are lower). Make sure the code that creates this monstrosity of a value rationalizes the case of fields in it.

Comment: Thanks guys. At the mercy of government data with the field that is causing issues. Think I might be overthinking things with retrieving the fields. UDF's and CLR SP's are way above my knowledge base.

Comment: I'm sure there is a simple approach, but having a major blonde moment.Something like         'person.givenname not like history.logmessage'      Doesn't seem to do the trick